# How to update 0 or null values with sequence number?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I need to update the values 0 and null in column batch so that the value continue the sequence for the year. The new value should start from the lowest 0/null value for the year.

```
id year batch
1  2005 null
2  2005 1
3  2005 2
4  2005 0
5  2006 0
6  2006 1
7  2006 2
8  2006 3
9  2006 null
10 2006 0
```

The result should be the following:

```
id year batch
1  2005 3
2  2005 1
3  2005 2
4  2005 4
5  2006 4
6  2006 1
7  2006 2
8  2006 3
9  2006 5
10 2006 6
```

Do you have any ideas? I believe that I have to use MAX value, but don't know how to continue.

Comment: use `lag` function and `exists`

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a new sequence using the window function `row_number` and update the data in the table.

Assuming your table is named `test`

```
UPDATE test 
set batch = new_batch
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id
  , year
  , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition BY year ORDER BY  NULLIF(batch, 0), id) new_batch
  FROM test
) new_values
WHERE new_values.id = test.id
```

The `NULLIF` function will set the result of the expression to null if it evaluates to the second argument. In this example, if batch is 0, it is set to null. Null values are placed last by default in an order by, which you can also specify explicitly using `NULLS LAST`.

A lag based solution would not work in postgresql because postgresql does not support the qualifer `ignore nulls` in the lag / lead window functions. Though this approach is valid in other databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count(..) over partition by .. order by ..` analytic function :

```
select id, year,
       count(id) over 
       (partition by year
        order by year, sign( coalesce(batch,0) ) desc, id ) as batch
  from t
 order by id
```

where we need to start to count after `non-null` and `non-zero` values of `batch` by use of (`sign( coalesce(batch,0) ) desc`) and this should be in the order of (`id`), and this counting should reset per each year ( `partition by year` ) in the order of year ( `order by year` )

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5a54b4ffbed94d24e3e3d22db17c1b55)</kbd>

If you don't only want to display but update also, then use :

```
update t t1
   set batch = t2.batch
  from ( select id,
                count(id) over 
                        (partition by year
                         order by coalesce(batch,0) , id ) as batch
                   from t
                   ) as t2
where t1.id = t2.id
```